# Building a cross category filter to show divs by class name(s) using checkboxes (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox, filtering

stackoverflow inspired me for building a "category filter" using checkboxes and I stuck half way. I want to achieve the following: Three categories (brand, class, color) are presented by three "checkbox-columns" inside a table:

```
<table id="filters" width="620px">
  <tr>
    <td width="144" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Audi" id="filter-Audi" >Audi<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="BMW" id="filter-BMW" >BMW<br>
    </td>
    <td width="233" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="Compact" id="filter-Compact" >Compact<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="Limousine" id="filter-Limousine" >Limousine<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="SUV" id="filter-SUV" >SUV<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="Sport" id="filter-Sport" >Sport<br>
    </td>
    <td width="233" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="silver" id="filter-silver" >silver<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="blue" id="filter-blue" >blue<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="red" id="filter-red" >red<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="white" id="filter-white" >white<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Depending on the selected checkboxes I want to display certain divs containing the class names identical to the checked checkbox IDs. This is already working. What I need now is a way to formulate an "exclude" filter for each category.

Means, if a user checks the following:

Audi & Limousine & red – only the divs containg those categories should appear. In my example, all divs containing Audi & Limousine & red apper but of course the BMW div also appear (which is wrong).

In other words: I need a additional "filtering method" that includes classes hirarchically by each category: i.e.: if a user checks Audi, the checkboxes for the second and third category should only refer to the div classes that contain Audi. If a user checks Audi & Compact & white the appearing divs have at least to contain all three classes.

jQuery part so far (found this on stackoverflow):

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    var re = new RegExp($("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join("|"));
    $.each($('.filterme'), function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this[re.source != "" && re.test($this.attr("class")) ? "slideDown" : "slideUp"]();
    });
});
```

I pushed the existing code to jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ar3PY/

Would love if someone could help here!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Change your HTML to include a class for each category (brand, class, color)

```
<table id="filters" width="620px">
  <tr>
    <td width="144" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" value="Audi" id="filter-Audi" >Audi<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" value="BMW" id="filter-BMW" >BMW<br>
    </td>
    <td width="233" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" value="Compact" id="filter-Compact" >Compact<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" value="Limousine" id="filter-Limousine" >Limousine<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" value="SUV" id="filter-SUV" >SUV<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" value="Sport" id="filter-Sport" >Sport<br>
    </td>
    <td width="233" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox" class="color"  value="silver" id="filter-silver" >silver<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="color"  value="blue" id="filter-blue" >blue<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="color" value="red" id="filter-red" >red<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="color" value="white" id="filter-white" >white<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Change your java script code to as follows:

```
var getFilter = function(category) {
    var filter = $("#filters ." + category + ":checked").map(function() {
        return "." + this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
    filter = (filter.length > 0) ? filter : "*";
    console.log(filter);
    return filter;
}

$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    var all = $(".filterme");
    var tgts = all.filter(getFilter("brand")).filter(getFilter("class")).filter(getFilter("color"));
    all.not(tgts).slideUp();
    tgts.slideDown();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ar3PY/2/

Comment: thanks for your help, but this approach excludes the checks within a column. If Audi alone is checked, every three divs containing the class Audi appear. Correct so far. But: now Audi & Limousine & Compact is checked... I expect that all divs appear, containing Audi AND Compact & Limousine. But with your function, both divs (Compact and Limousine) disappear. You know, every checkbos in a column should behave in an "additional" way, but checkboxes in a row in an "exclusive" way. Any Idea?

Comment: This comment is contradicting the explanation you provided in the question. "I need a additional "filtering method" that includes classes hirarchically by each category". Can you clarify?

Comment: The filter method I'm using is looking for every checked checkbox and their corresponding ID. And if one of these IDs is found as a div class, then the correspoding div appears. This is OK for checkboxes within a column (category). What I need in addition is something like a breadcrump for all three categories (columns).

Comment: just think of the following situation: Someone wants information about all Audi, Compact, Limousine, silver models. In my example, only two divs should appear after checking those 4 boxes:  The one for the Audi A1 and A4

Comment: Gotcha.. let me see if can comeup with a solution

Comment: thank you so much! Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for! Nice work, really.

Comment: @bohnert : You could vote up the posts and pick an answer as correct in return ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your html and came up with the result.
The changes I made were to add a class to the td tags like below.

```
<table id="filters" width="620px">
  <tr>
    <td  class="car" width="144" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Audi" id="filter-Audi" >Audi<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="BMW" id="filter-BMW" >BMW<br>
    </td>
    <td  class="type" width="233" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="Compact" id="filter-Compact" >Compact<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="Limousine" id="filter-Limousine" >Limousine<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="SUV" id="filter-SUV" >SUV<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="Sport" id="filter-Sport" >Sport<br>
    </td>
    <td  class="color" width="233" align="left" valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="silver" id="filter-silver" >silver<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="blue" id="filter-blue" >blue<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="red" id="filter-red" >red<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="white" id="filter-white" >white<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Next I used a modified version of Chandu's answer to seperately filter out by category in the following manner.

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function () {
            var filterCarString = $("#filters :checkbox:checked").length == 0 ? "*" :
            $("#filters .car :checkbox:checked").length == 0 ? "*" :
                   $("#filters .car :checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                       return "." + this.value;
                   }).get().join(",.");

            var filterTypeString = $("#filters :checkbox:checked").length == 0 ? "*" :
                    $("#filters .type :checkbox:checked").length == 0 ? "*" :
                   $("#filters .type :checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                       return "." + this.value;
                   }).get().join(",.");

            var filterColorString = $("#filters :checkbox:checked").length == 0 ? "*" :
                  $("#filters .color :checkbox:checked").length == 0 ? "*" :
                   $("#filters .color :checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                       return "." + this.value;
                   }).get().join(",.");


            var filterTgts = $('.filterme');
            var elems = filterTgts.filter(filterCarString);
                elems = elems.filter(filterTypeString);
                elems = elems.filter(filterColorString).slideDown();

            filterTgts.not(elems).slideUp();
 });
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I understand you approach but wasn't able to make it work in a rush... but from the syntax and logic it looks fine. Hm, will try it later when I have some more time. Anyway, thanks for you effort. I really appreciate what you are all doing here within "minutes".